# Mirror image on x axis (or axis origin to lower left)

Tags: x11, xcb

I have an `xcb_image_t` and point to some pixel data using `uint8_t *data` data member. Then I found 3 ways to show/transfer it on window:

1. Directly `xcb_image_put(connection, window, gc, image,...)`
2. Put it on a `xcb_pixmap_t` and then xcb_copy_area
   `xcb_image_put(connection, pixmap, gc, image,...)`
   `xcb_copy_area(connection, pixmap, window, gc, ...)`
3. Put it on a pixmap and then call `xcb_present_pixmap_checked(...)`

I want to flip the image on the x axis (or some other arbitrary 2D transformation), in order make it look like the axis origin is located at the bottom left (instead of upper left) corner. How can i get this to work (obviously without manually transforming my pixels)

Comment: You can use XRender and its capability to transform a picture. I don't know how to do that with XCB, there ought to be bindings bit I have no idea where to find them. And of course this requires XRender. being present.

Comment: After looking up what XRender is, I believe it is too complicated for what i need. I just need to flip the image on the x axis. Maybe if I give a negative stride somewhere would do the trick, but I don't know where.